# Nested IF Statement (price bands)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a formula using the following parameters:

`=IF(E20<=500,E20*.90,IF(E20<=1000,E20*.80,IF(E20<5000,E20*.70,IF(E20<=10000,E20*.60,IF(E20<999999,E20*.50`

I want the formula to calculate the price if the quantity falls within the range but am missing something with the formula above.

Could someone please point out the mistake and offer a suggestion or correction?

Comment: Please provide proper formula. I think you are missing something.

Comment: Missing the closing brackets? )))))

Comment: Also missing the condition when E20 > 999999

Answer (score 4):

Since struggling with nested IFs (understandably!) you might be better off with a lookup table. Say name an array as below `LT`;

```
1       0.9
500     0.8
1000    0.7
5000    0.6
10000   0.5
```

and apply `=VLOOKUP(E20,LT,2)*E20`

Comment: They should be `501`, `1001`, `5001` and `10000` since there's less than or equal to :) But this is also a good alternate approach!

Comment: Hmm, right that they could be wrong as well. I didn't notice the inconsistency between the inequalities until now.

Answer (score 0):

With this, you check if cell A1 value falls between 100 and 200

```
=IF(A1 < 200; IF(A1 > 100; "ok"; "no"); "no")
```

Instead of "ok", you can insert your price calculation.
With this, you check if A1 < 100, if it is not then it checks if A1 < 200, and again if not it checks if A1 < 1000. If none of these conditions are true, it says "A1 > 1000"

```
=IF(A1 < 100; "A1<100"; IF(A1 < 200; "A1 < 200"; IF(A1 < 1000; "A1 < 1000"; "A1 > 1000")))
```

Again, instead of the optut string, you can insert your price calculation

Hope it helps, regards